# Parsing vars from Ansble to powershell

Tags: powershell, ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower, ansible-module

I have created my own module. This module executes a powershellscript.

But now I need to overgive them some variables, how can I do this.

I already have tried with this:

> $data = Get-Content $args[0] | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

But that doesnt work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why use `Out-String` when you can just use `Get-Content -Raw`?

Comment: @AdminOfThings this was the solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping to `Out-String` is not necessary here. You can utilize the `-Raw` switch on [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1) if you want to read file contents as a single string:

```
$data = Get-Content $args[0] -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```